# Probability After Sampling Without Replacement Until Success

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've found a lot of examples of probabilities for sampling without replacement and sampling until success, but I'm curious of how a combination of the two effects future trials. Let's say I have a bag containing three different colors of marbles, red, black, and white. If I remove marbles from the bag until I remove a red marble how do I determine the expected value of how many black and white marbles I have removed? How can I determine the probability that the next marble removed is red, white, or black?

Comment: Are you looking for the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)?